# Lenovo thinkpad T440s stuck on boot (broken BIOS?), after installing Fedora workstation 36 from USB

Tags: fedora, bios

I have installed `Fedora workstation 36` with USB media by Fedora media writer onto my laptop, Lenovo T440s. (The previous OS was Windows 10 pro)

Installation seemed to complete successfully, but after reboot the laptop
stuck on boot.

Boot menu shows only `PCI LAN`, so I tried to PXE install with tools like AOMEI/Minitools, but host machine seems not receiving packet.

Instead it shows sometimes `BPF version check error` as well.

What I tried:

- BIOS reset to default
- disabled secure boot
- legacy mode ( or both..
  ->
  any BIOS command was not successful.

Now I think the BIOS itself became broken by installing Fedora workstation.
So do I have to replace BIOS chip on motherboard, or reprogram it with RT809F + PEB-1 + EDID..?

(Someone says it can be fixed without soldering:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1955416
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiFHhEqluCY&ab_channel=NorthridgeFix
https://droidrant.com/how-do-i-fix-a-corrupted-lenovo-bios/

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any idea to fix?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Can you get into the BIOS at all? Like, the menu?

Comment: Thank you, I have added photo of BIOS setting screen. ( though to show it, I need to try removing ram, CMOS remove, and reboot many times.. usual shortcut keys not working..

Comment: As for the CMOS, it might be that the battery needs to be replaced (not the laptop battery, but the BIOS battery). Have you tried to enter the BIOS and reset it to factory settings? When you say the 'shortcut keys aren't working', do you mean that the function keys (`F1`-`F12`) do not work? If so, have you tried holding down the `Fn` key while pressing one of the function keys?

Comment: Thank you so much for response, Telometto. I tried some times BIOS `Load Setup defaults`. and 'function keys are not working' means screen stuck even when I press some buttons(like enter, F1,F10,F12, etc.) on boot. (Yes, I tried key with `Fn` as well)
but I can enter BIOS settings only when I try removing 1 ram and remove CMOS battery some times, occasionally. so it looks like capricious..

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not entirely sure on what it could be, unfortunately. You could try to ask the question over at superuser.com - they accept hardware-related questions, too - so someone might be able to help you there. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.